# Laravel how to allow nullable when also minimum length is required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

How can I allow an array to be empty when also a minimum length is required? I'm using `Laravel 5.8`

I have this in my controller:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
   'skills' => 'array|min:5|nullable'
], $errors);
```

but that does not work. So, can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the sample data to be validated? For example, how can an array have a min value? You mean its length?

Comment: @Shobi the array must contain at least 5 items but it should also be allowede to be empty, so yes, its the length of the array I'm referring to :-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to check for nullable first. and then, if not null, check for the length.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
   'skills' => 'nullable|array|min:5'
], $errors);
```

Comment: what does not work?? tested in my end. works fine if the array is null and if not null checks it's length.

Comment: Isn't this answer same as the question?

Comment: no it's not. the order of the validation is different.